# Storing temporary UI state in a Reactive Dictionary don't work

Tags: meteor, reactive

I am following the default tutorial and I am stuck here: [Step7: Storing temporary UI state in a Reactive Dictionary](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/temporary-ui-state)

As soon as I insert the `import { ReactiveDict } from 'meteor/reactive-dict'`;
, the application no longer displays the body. it only displays the gradient in the background.
Although I continue the tutorial it does not work out.

Comment: Did you add the package? `meteor add reactive-dict`

Comment: Always keep console open on browser, this resolves 70% of the problem and help you take needed steps.

Comment: I didn't add the package. Thanks @Jankapunkt